# WordPress Shortcode output is duplicated on page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I created an ACF image field that I want to add in my product description.

I then created a shortcode via this code:

```
function imgun_shortcode() {
$imgun = get_field('imgun')['sizes']['thumbnail']; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)?>
<div>
    <img src="<?php echo $imgun;?>">
</div> <?php 
}

add_shortcode('imgun', 'imgun_shortcode');
```

I then add this shortcode in the extension "block":

[image]

I add this page via a shortcode in my product description, the image field is positioned in 2 times and not at the place of the shortcode I do not understand why. My other ACF "text" fields do not have this problem.

[image]

Do you have an idea?

Comment: You can't echo shortcode output.

Comment: I just updated the code in my question (error in my input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't echo the output from a shortcode.  `Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode.` https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

You could either do this...

```
function imgun_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    $imgun = get_field( 'imgun' )['sizes']['thumbnail']; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)?>
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $imgun ); ?>">
    </div> <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'imgun', 'imgun_shortcode' );
```

Or you could do this...

```
function imgun_shortcode() {
    $imgun = get_field('imgun')['sizes']['thumbnail']; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size).
    return '<div><img src="' . esc_url( $imgun ) . '"></div>';
}

add_shortcode('imgun', 'imgun_shortcode');
```

Comment: thank you very much !!