# Wordpress custom plugin development issue: Class function that outputs HTML, outputs duplicate HTML in the WP editor page

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins, wp-editor

I'm developing a custom WP plugin with my own custom PHP Class with its function. I need it to output the html from the `display_papers()` class/function, by using a custom shortcode on my WP page.

As you can see below, I even thought perhaps that `ob_start()` had to be used (code commented out below).

The issue I have is, the echoing out of the HTML is displaying TWICE in the WP EDITOR (not on the front of page - which shows correctly) and even in the Elementor editor. The first (duplicate) echo almost seems as if it's echoing outside the html/shortcode container of the WP editor (when I refresh editor page, it renders first before the editor page is loaded.

I'm baffled with the following, what seems a simple function in a class:

The class:

```
class Pastpapers {
    public function __construct() {
        // nothing here yet
    }

    public function display_papers() {
        //ob_start();
    
        echo '<h2>hello biscuit!</h2>';

        //ob_get_contents();
        //ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

I instantiate my custom class and call the `display_papers()` function within it (wrapped in my custom shortcode on a WP page):

```
// the paper list shortcode
function dbase_list_papers( $atts) {

    $pastpapers = new Pastpapers(); // instantiate class
    $pastpapers->display_papers();  // call class function to echo html onto shortcode page

}
add_shortcode ('list_papers', 'dbase_list_papers');
```

EDIT TO ADD: One thing that crossed my mind is: Is it a possible passing of html headers issue? Although I don't get any errors at all (ie. `WP_DEBUG`)

Comment: You can't echo shortcode output.  Shortcodes by definition must not produce output, so you need to return your content. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#more-information - unless you are using output buffering, but then you still have to `return ob_get_contents()`

Comment: @HowardE You are genius.. thank you. You should rather recreate your post as an answer, so I can tick it as the solution. In the class function `display_papers()`, I created an `$html` variable storing the html code, then returned it instead. When I call it within the shortcode code, I changed it to `return $pastpapers->display_papers();`

Comment: Mario, thanks... I've already answered similar questions... here's one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027743/wordpress-shortcode-output-is-duplicated-on-page/70028514#70028514 essentially the same issue.